# Lua for premake4 beginners: is 'variable = {"a", "b"}' same thing as 'variable {"a", "b"}'?

Tags: lua, premake

In premake we have constructs like  `files  { "**.h", "**.cpp" }` would `files = { "**.h", "**.cpp" }` be same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The construct is the same as

```
files({"**.h", "**.cpp"})
```

that is, a function call. In general you can leave out the parenthesis if a function is called with a single literal argument:

```
print "Hello world!"
```